# Inserting .csvs into an SQLite DB in Java

Tags: java, sqlite, csv

Hey all. So I have a collection of csv files which I would like to insert into an sqlite DB in my Java program as tables. I googled around and searched SO as well, but I can't find any tutorial on how to insert these csv files into the sqlite DB. I am using this sqlite wrapper: [Zentus SQLiteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/).

So let's assume I have a csv file with the following inside of it:

```
1,John,Doe,5.0
2,Jane,Smith,5.0
```

How could I create a table and insert these values into it?

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Update: OK so I found this guide: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles but the syntax is confusing me a bit. Specifically:

```
sqlite> create table test (id integer, datatype_id integer, level integer, meaning text);    
sqlite> .separator ","    
sqlite> .import no_yes.csv test
```

I understand what this is doing, it says the separator will be a comma, and to import the file no_yes.csv into the table test. However, this is how I have been doing sql statements as per the JDBC guide:

```
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
stat.executeUpdate("drop table if exists test;");
stat.executeUpdate("create table test (id, name, value);");
```

I tried doing this to represent the separator line:

```
stat.executeUpdate("separator ','");
```

AND

```
stat.executeUpdate(".separator ','");
```

But both give me an error. How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the table first. 
Then you can read the csv files with something like that:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your file"));
String line;
while ( (line=br.readLine()) != null)
{
         String[] values = line.split(",");    //your seperator

         //Convert String to right type. Integer, double, date etc.
         stat.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO yourTable VALUES('"+value[0]+"','"+value[1]...
         //Use a PeparedStatemant, it´s easier and safer 
}
br.close();
```